# Python: Check if a directory is an alias

Tags: macos, python-2.7, directory-structure

Does python have a simple function for checking if a directory is an actual directory or if it's just an alias to another directory? I'm trying to list all files/folders in a directory but because of these alias folders, I'm getting a lost of stuff that looks like this:

/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bundle/Home/bundle/Home/bundle/Home/bundle/Home/bundle/Home/bundle/Home/bundle/Home/bundle/Home/bundle/Home/bundle/Home/bundle

[image: Directory Alias]

I know I can write a function that will compare paths and quit if it seems like I'm going in circles, but is there a simple function that does exactly that that I'm not aware of? 
E.g.
 `os.isAlias( …pathname… )`

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a version of `os.path.realpath` that works on Mac aliases as well as on symbolic links *under Python 2*:

```
from Carbon import File
def osx_realpath (path):
    return File.FSResolveAliasFile(path, True)[0].as_pathname()
```

If you call osx_realpath on each directory before you recurse into it you should avoid duplication. Alternatively you could define something like

```
def is_osx_realpath (path):
    return path == osx_realpath(path)
```

Here you have to worry a little about false negatives, however. If you filter for is_osx_realpath and the path you start with is an alias, your program will stop without looking at anything.

So far I don't know of a way to do this under Python 3. I have a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21244781/what-replaces-the-now-deprecated-carbon-file-fsresolvealiasfile-in-python-on-osx) where I'm hoping for an answer. Right now I can't do better than using [subprocess.call](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to [invoke something that does the check on the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175094/os-x-terminal-command-to-resolve-path-of-an-alias/17570232#17570232).

EDIT: I should add that not only is Carbon.File not available in Python 3, but it is deprecated and so is best avoided in Python 2 as well--however it's the most pragmatic solution I know of for Python 2 at present.

EDIT 2: here is a way to check if a file is an alias that I believe to be Python 3-friendly. However, I don't have code to resolve the alias. I believe you need PyObjC installed.

```
from AppKit import NSWorkspace
def is_alias (path):
    uti, err = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().typeOfFile_error_(
        os.path.realpath(path), None)
    if err:
        raise Exception(unicode(err))
    else:
        return "com.apple.alias-file" == uti
```

([source](http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/Creator-type-and-other-means-of-file-detection-td2157634.html))

Comment: This returns a false for an alias(yay!), but an error for symlinks: `File.FSResolveAliasFile(path, True)[0].as_pathname()`  `MacOS.Error: (-120, 'Directory not found')`. Right now, I'm pretty much resorting to subprocess calls. Specifically, `command = ["mdfind", "kMDItemKind == 'Alias'"]`                               `subprocess.call(command)`                                         will print out all Alias files which I'm guessing is similar to what you're doing…? (If it isn't and you have no idea what I'm talking about, `mdfind` == spotlight find and `mdls` is roughly analogous to `ls`).

Comment: God, sorry for the horrible formatting. Double space isn't new-lining things for me. Also, I would upvote your answer but I don't have enough votes to upvote(!) :-/

Comment: Not sure you can get newlines into comments. I confirmed that the code above works with symbolic links on my machine. Have you tried calling `os.path.exists` to make sure the link you're querying on actually exists? At any rate you could catch the exception or check `os.path.islink` first.

Comment: `os.path.exists` returns _true_ for alias and _false_ for symlinks. `os.path.islink` returns _false_ for alias and _true for symlinks. I figured that would fix it since I could just write an if-else statement that would catch either occurrence. Alas, .app executables return false for both `os.path.islink` and `os.path.exists` (false for `os.path.isdir` and `os.path.isfile` too!). I haven't  yet tried out your Edit2 method above since I'm still in Python 3 but I've accepted your answer anyway since it looks like the closest to a solution so far. Thanks for all the help! :)

Comment: _"since I'm still in Python 3"_. Sorry, I mean Python 2.7.

Comment: Tip for people coming here and seeing `AppKit` in the import: it is **not** the Python package of the same name on PyPI. It is, in fact, a different package provided by `pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC`. Do **not** try to get it via `pip install AppKit`. Instead, use `pip install pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is incorrect.
While it is true that Finder reports symlinks as alias, they are distinct things.

Symlinks are a basic feature of UNIX, but alias are a Apple only feature.
If you doubt this create a symlink to a directory and an alias. The symlink will be small typically 50-100 bytes, whereas the alias can be several MB.

`os.path.islink( … )` will report symlinks, but not alias.

I am not sure how you would find them in Python, but the following link shows other methods.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21151368/838253

Comment: You are correct! Apparently, the same symbol is used for aliases and symlinks on a Mac and the Home/bundle path I posted above is actually a  symlink and not an alias which is why `os.path.islink( … )` worked for me.


Thanks for the link. I'll go over it in more detail later tonight and see if it holds the answer.

Comment: (ugh, sorry. I can't vote up your answer! it says I need at least 15 reps!)

Comment: so anyone has an idea what an alias really is, and what is it for?

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether a file or directory is an alias with the `GetFileInfo` command in Mac OS X.  `GetFileInfo -aa foo` prints a line with "1" if foo is an alias and "0" if not.

```
import subprocess

def is_alias(path):
    return subprocess.check_output(["GetFileInfo", "-aa", path]) == "1\n"
```

Seems a little sad to spawn a process for every check, but I think this works with versions of Mac OS X since probably 10.4.4 (2006), 32-bit, 64-bit, Python 2 and Python 3.  The version of GetFileInfo I have (from 2009) is a "universal" i386 + PPC binary.

GetFileInfo is part of Xcode, which is large, but you can download the command-line tools separately (see the "Separate Download" section [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-and-later-install-command-line-tools)).

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/GetFileInfo.1.html

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I just ran into this myself.

I have no perfect method for checking if the file is an alias, however, if using `mimetypes`, python will return `None` for an alias or a symlink. Might be useful in some situations. I've only tested this in python 3.8 on macOS Big Sur.

```py
import mimetypes

for idx, f in enumerate(filepaths):
    type = mimetypes.guess_type(f)[0]
    print(f"type is: {type}")
```

returns (without my added comments):

```sh
type is: None # <-- Folder Alias
type is: None # <-- File Alias
type is: text/x-python
type is: None # <-- Folder Alias
type is: video/mp4
type is: image/png
type is: None # <-- Folder Alias
type is: None # <-- Symlink
type is: image/png
type is: application/zip
type is: image/png
type is: image/jpeg
type is: None # <-- Symlink
```

I ran some files through exiftool just to see what types they returned, and aliases and symlinks both showed the following:

```sh
File Type                       : ALIAS
File Type Extension             : alias
MIME Type                       : application/x-macos
```

You might be able to init the mimetypes for these, but haven't tested and not sure if it will give false positives if anything else shows up as `application/x-macos`

Comment: The issue with this solution is that some files also return None as type and you therefore can't identify precisely and with certainty the aliases