# How can get a list of files in a specific directory ignoring the symbolic links using python?

Tags: python

I need to process the filenames from a directory by creating the list of the filenames.
But my resulting list contains entries for symbolic links too. How can I get pure filenames in a particular directory using python.

I have tried:`os.walk,os.listdir,os.path.isfile`

But all are including symbolic links of type `'filename~'` to the list :(

The    `glob.glob` adds the path to the list which I don't need.

I need to use it in a code like this:

```
files=os.listdir(folder)    
for f in files:
     dosomething(like find similar file f in other folder)
```

Any help? Or please redirect me to the right answer. Thanks

Edit: the tilde sign is at end

Comment: filter based on `not file.startswith('~')`

Comment: If you need to support OS X aliases, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21245832/2829764

Comment: @kuzzooroo am using Linux

Comment: Thanks @PadraicCunningham. I used 'files = [f for f in os.listdir(folder) if not f.endswith('~')]'. It seems to be working.
Sorry the tilde sign was at end and have edited my question.

Comment: if it is at the end use `not file.endswith('~')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get regular files in a directory:

```
import os
from stat import S_ISREG

for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    path = os.path.join(folder, filename)
    try:
        st = os.lstat(path) # get info about the file (don't follow symlinks)
    except EnvironmentError:
        continue # file vanished or permission error
    else:
        if S_ISREG(st.st_mode): # is regular file?
           do_something(filename)
```

If you still see `'filename~'` filenames then it means that they are not actually symlinks. Just filter them using their names:

```
filenames = [f for f in os.listdir(folder) if not f.endswith('~')]
```

Or using `fnmatch`:

```
import fnmatch

filenames = fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(folder), '*[!~]')
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried 'fnmatch' which you previously suggested. Seems to be not working.

Comment: @Kaur: That is why I've deleted it. I've added `fnmatch` solution that works.

Comment: Yes this one 'fnmatch' is working. Earlier was '*~'. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `os.path.islink(yourfile)` to check if yourfile is symlinked, and exclude it.

Something like this works for me:

```
folder = 'absolute_path_of_yourfolder' # without ending /
res = []
for f in os.listdir(folder):
    absolute_f = os.path.join(folder, f)
    if not os.path.islink(absolute_f) and not os.path.isdir(absolute_f):
        res.append(f)

res # will get you the files not symlinked nor directory
...
```

Comment: I tried files = [f for f in os.listdir(folder) if not os.path.islink(os.path.join(folder,f))] 
But the list of files still contain symbolic links :(

Comment: @Kaur, I've included a sample which works on my laptop